Get the Json extract from one column and compare with another column
I have the data shown here, I am expecting to compare with transactionTimeStamp > CreatedDate_TimeStamp where
Config_MSG is one of the column in json format



Id
Config_MSG
CreatedDate_TimeStamp




1234
{"memberId":"1", "message":{"transactionTimeStamp":"2024-08-20 14:17:29"}}
2024-08-19 14:17:29


12345
{"memberId":"2", "message":{"transactionTimeStamp":"2024-08-22 14:17:29"}}
2024-08-18 14:17:29


12346
{"memberId":"3", "message":{"transactionTimeStamp":"2024-08-18 14:17:29"}}
2024-08-18 14:17:29



I am trying to use JSON_EXTRACT where it's getting error with might be syntax or SQL Server does not supported this

You have tagged both mysql and sql-server. Which one are you using? Query SELECT @@version; and report exactly what the result is. It's important to tag your question accurately so you get a correct answer. A solution for one brand of SQL database is not necessarily going to work on another.

I am using SQl Server

Assuming you have VALID JSON ... look at transactionTimeStamp ... no quotes.   You can use JSON_VALUE().    For example: JSON_Value([Config_MSG],'$.transactionTimeStamp')

please check the payload above , it has nested json payload and i need to compare with transactionTimeStamp > CreatedDate_TimeStamp

It didn't originally

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

As you are using SQL Server, for your requirement you should use JSON_VALUE,
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, JSON_VALUE(config_msg, '$.messgae.transactionTimeStamp')) > createddate_timestamp;

Refer to this for full sql server execution: dbfiddle

Hi Lisan,  it's saying the error  "the conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datatime resulted in an out-of-range value @Lhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/6316577/lisan-al-gaib

could you please share the datatype of columns used? Also share the exact error message? I am not getting error, you can refer to the dbfiddle, as it depends on table definition and sql server version too.

Please try the following solution.
It is following the same minimal reproducible example pattern. You copy it to SSMS as-is, run it, and it is working as expected.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Config_MSG NVARCHAR(MAX), CreatedDate_TimeStamp DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Config_MSG, CreatedDate_TimeStamp) VALUES
(N'{
    "memberId": "1",
    "message": {
        "transactionTimeStamp": "2024-08-20 14:17:29"
    }
}', '2024-08-19 14:17:29'),
(N'{
    "memberId": "2",
    "message": {
        "transactionTimeStamp": "2024-08-22 14:17:29"
    }
}', '2024-08-18 14:17:29');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * 
    , CONVERT(DATETIME, JSON_VALUE(config_msg, '$.message.transactionTimeStamp')) AS transactionTimeStamp
FROM @tbl
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, JSON_VALUE(config_msg, '$.message.transactionTimeStamp')) > createddate_timestamp;

Output



id
Config_MSG
CreatedDate_TimeStamp
transactionTimeStamp





1
{   "memberId": "1",   "message": {
"transactionTimeStamp": "2024-08-20 14:17:29"   }  }
2024-08-19 14:17:29.000
2024-08-20 14:17:29.000


2
{   "memberId": "2",   "message": {
"transactionTimeStamp": "2024-08-22 14:17:29"   }  }
2024-08-18 14:17:29.000
2024-08-22 14:17:29.000



